# Simple HTTPServer python on background

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this script, I do not know how to have it running in the background, cause when i close the session it close too. I tried putting it on crontab but not find the index.html and shows the list of files in /.

```
#! /opt/python3/bin/python3

from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

port = 8000

httpd = HTTPServer(('', port), CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
print("Starting simple_httpd on port: " + str(httpd.server_port))
httpd.serve_forever()`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you are asking about how to detach the program from your shell ... here is a few options

1. ./scriptname.py >/dev/null 2>&1 & # sends the program to the background
2. Use [gnu-screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) (or similar) ... run your program via screen and you can bring it back up when you log back in
3. Daemonize your program properly

Update:

Recently I have not written a single daemon in python. The days of forking twice or using a daemon library seem to be well behind us. I currently use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) and have heard good things about [circus](http://circus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/rationale/). These are just a small set of extra options you can use to deploy python daemons.